# Forecasting Headcount in R

Tags: r, forecast

I want to simply see the forecasted number of headcount for hiring in next 4 months.

My data has three variables

HiringYear, hiringMonth and Number of Hires(number of distinct orders)

My data can be reproduced

`structure(list(hireyear = c(2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), month = c(12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L), number_of_distinct_orders = c(106L, 
150L, 43L, 39L, 46L, 28L, 44L, 15L, 23L, 22L, 12L, 47L, 15L, 
1998L, 75L, 165L, 158L, 75L, 49L, 46L, 51L, 25L, 33L, 37L, 36L, 
67L, 167L, 41L, 49L, 41L, 263L, 49L, 62L, 48L, 51L, 46L, 37L, 
67L, 40L, 12L)), row.names = 245:284, class = "data.frame")`

Comment: And what is your question? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to generate forecasts. This would be a good place to start: https://tidyverts.github.io/tidy-forecasting-principles/

Answer (score 2):

the most simple prediction using `predict()`:

```
Model <- lm(data = df,number_of_distinct_orders~. )
predict(Model, newdata=df) 

       245        246        247        248        249        250        251        252        253        254        255 
 11.711985 272.554432 246.690574 220.826717 194.962859 169.099001 143.235144 117.371286  91.507428  65.643571  39.779713 
       256        257        258        259        260        261        262        263        264        265        266 
 13.915855 -11.948002 248.894444 223.030587 197.166729 171.302871 145.439014 119.575156  93.711298  67.847441  41.983583 
       267        268        269        270        271        272        273        274        275        276        277 
 16.119725  -9.744132 -35.607990 225.234457 199.370599 173.506742 147.642884 121.779026  95.915169  70.051311  44.187453 
       278        279        280        281        282        283        284 
 18.323596  -7.540262 -33.404120 -59.267978 201.574469 175.710612 149.846754
```

Just the first 4 months:

```
predict(Model, newdata=df)[1:4]
  245       246       247       248 
11.71199 272.55443 246.69057 220.82672
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally it pays to start off very simple and add complexity as you need it. It may be instructive to do a few scatter plots and histograms to understand the distribution of each variable and how they correlate to each other.

The next step would be a simple linear regression to gauge how well the head count can be described in the simplest of ways by the other variables.

This will likely not give you the best fit in which case you can then branch out into exploring more non-linear regressions. Or, I would suggest checking out this post to learn how to incorporate time series analysis into your forecasting. 
https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting/